# How to position JavaFX chart area only

Tags: javafx-8, linechart

This question is related to this question: [How to draw multiple axis on a chart using JAVAFX Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667405/how-to-draw-multiple-axis-on-a-chart-using-javafx-charts)

I'm trying to overlay two JavaFX line charts and offset their axes. I'm using various values for the y axis which may or may not effect the position of the main chart area. Right now I'm using the following code to position the charts, but I cant figure out a way to absolutely position the main chart area.

```
    primaryChart.setTranslateY(-50.0);
    primaryChart.setTranslateX(80.0);
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(primaryChart, 50.0);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(primaryChart, 80.0);
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(primaryChart, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(primaryChart, 0.0);
    secondaryChart.setTranslateY(-50.0);
    secondaryChart.setTranslateX(98.0);
    secondaryChart.getXAxis().setTranslateY(50.0);
    secondaryChart.getYAxis().setTranslateX(-98.0);
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(secondaryChart, 50.0);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(secondaryChart, 52.0);
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(secondaryChart, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(secondaryChart, 0.0);
```

These commands move the whole chart but I just want to move the charting area. Here are some pictures explaining what's going on.

[image: A properly aligned Chart]

[image: The chart with the axis shifted due to adding a new axis.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to maintain the position of the chart area by setting the preferred width of the Y axis to 80px.