# Move tick label JavaFx 2

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, linechart, axis-labels

Is it possible to move/shift the tick labels into the chart. Currently I see api's to hide/show tick labels is there an API that moves the tick labels inside the chart? If there isn't an API then is there a technique that I can use/apply to get this done?

Current code

```
public class Graph extends Application{
private NumberAxis xAxis;
private NumberAxis yAxis;

public static void main(final String[] args)
{
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
{
    xAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 300, 20);
    xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
    xAxis.setAnimated(false);
    xAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);
    xAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(false);
    xAxis.setTickMarkVisible(false);

    yAxis = new NumberAxis(30, 240, 30);
    yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
    yAxis.setAnimated(false);
    yAxis.setTickMarkVisible(false);
    yAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);
    yAxis.setMinorTickCount(3);

    final LineChart<Number, Number> ctg = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

    ctg.setAnimated(false);
    ctg.setCreateSymbols(false);
    ctg.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);
    ctg.setLegendVisible(false);
    ctg.setHorizontalGridLinesVisible(true);
    ctg.setVerticalGridLinesVisible(true);

    Series<Number, Number> series = new LineChart.Series<>();
    ctg.getData().add(series);

    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i += 5) {

        XYChart.Series minorYGrid = new XYChart.Series();
        minorYGrid.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, 30));
        minorYGrid.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, 240));
        ctg.getData().add(minorYGrid);
    }

    for (int i = 40; i <= 240; i += 10) {

        XYChart.Series minorXGrid = new XYChart.Series();
        minorXGrid.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(0, i));
        minorXGrid.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(500, i));
        ctg.getData().add(minorXGrid);
    }

    final Scene scene = new Scene(ctg, 1600, 400);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("resources/application.css");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
}
```

Current result

[image]

Expected result
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Translating a Single Axis**

You can translate the y axis on the chart.

For example:

```
yAxis.translateXProperty().bind(
    xAxis.widthProperty().divide(2)
);
```

To ensure the axis is displayed on top of the chart, you could set the depth buffer to true on the scene and set the z co-ordinate of the yAxis to -1.

```
yAxis.setTranslateZ(-1);
```

**Translating Multiple Axes**

Your "Expected result" actually has multiple vertical axes.  Unfortunately there is no clone method to clone a node in JavaFX.  So you will have to create a new axis and layer it on top of the chart.  One way to accomplish that (which is a bit overkill and inefficient), is to create a completely new chart and layer it on top of the old one, similar to what is done in the solution to [draw layers of XYCharts](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/3668862).  The other way to do it, which is probably preferable but a bit trickier, would be just create another axis and stack it over the original chart.

**Sample Code**

[image: multi-axis chart]

*MultiAxisChart.java*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MultiAxisChart extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final StackPane chartStack = createChartStack();

        final Scene scene = new Scene(chartStack, 1600, 400, true);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private StackPane createChartStack() {
        LineChart<Number, Number> bottomChart = createChart();
        LineChart<Number, Number> topChart    = createChart();

        bottomChart.getYAxis().translateXProperty().bind(
                bottomChart.getXAxis().widthProperty().multiply(1.0/3)
        );
        topChart.getYAxis().translateXProperty().bind(
                topChart.getXAxis().widthProperty().multiply(2.0/3)
        );

        bottomChart.getYAxis().setTranslateZ(-1);
        topChart.getYAxis().setTranslateZ(-1);

        topChart.getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getResource(
                "overlay-chart.css"
        ).toExternalForm());

        return new StackPane(bottomChart, topChart);
    }

    private LineChart<Number, Number> createChart() {
        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 300, 20);
        xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
        xAxis.setAnimated(false);
        xAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);
        xAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(false);
        xAxis.setTickMarkVisible(false);

        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(30, 240, 30);
        yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
        yAxis.setAnimated(false);
        yAxis.setTickMarkVisible(false);
        yAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);
        yAxis.setMinorTickCount(3);

        final LineChart<Number, Number> ctg = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

        ctg.setAnimated(false);
        ctg.setCreateSymbols(false);
        ctg.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);
        ctg.setLegendVisible(false);
        ctg.setHorizontalGridLinesVisible(true);
        ctg.setVerticalGridLinesVisible(true);

        return ctg;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*overlay-chart.css*

```
/** file: overlay-chart.css (place in same directory as MultiAxisChart) */
.chart-plot-background {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to 
1. move 30 and 240 inside the graph boundary
2. center the y-axis labels over the y-axis line
3. set the y-axis line transparent while the label still appears
The expected result screenshot is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, that can all be done SDS: 1 is already done in my solution 2 is an additional translate request and 3 is a css style.  I am not going to update this solution with those modifications though.